"Firebase deploy --only functions" results in messages relating to extensions
I recently deployed a firebase function using:
firebase deploy --only functions

The console output was:
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8848

✔  extensions: required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  extensions: ensuring required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  extensions: required API firebaseextensions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  extensions: ensuring required API compute.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  extensions: required API compute.googleapis.com is enabled
i  extensions: By installing an extension instance onto a Firebase project, you accept the Firebase Extensions User Terms of Service: https://firebase.google.com/terms/extensions/user
? Do you accept the Firebase Extensions User Terms of Service? (Y/n) 

I am confused because:

I don't know what "installing an extension instance onto a Firebase project" means.
I don't know why it is talking/asking about extensions because:

I have not added that feature to my firebase project. (If I go to the extensions section of the firebase console, it behaves as if I have not activated it (it's all promo material)).
I explicity used "--only functions" in the deploy command


If I answer "No" to the conditions, it makes absolutely no apparent difference to the following script actions/output/success.

Can anyone confirm that this is normal for some known reason?
I am on Mac using firebase tools version 13.15.4

No one can know what should happen when you run the Firebase CLI without also seeing your project configuration.  The CLI uses firebase.json, as well as your project directory contents, to determine which Firebase products are in use and what to do during deployment.  If you think that the CLI is doing the wrong thing given the contents of that file, you should file an issue on firebase-tools, as Stack Overflow is unlikely to be of help.

Thanks for taking the time to respond to stackoverflow questions.  With all due respect since I barely understand this stuff, I was trying to avoid the hassle of bug reporting with all the required paperwork by simply confirming whetheror not this is normal behavior.

I suppose the determining factor is what exactly the cli is looking for inside firebase.json or the project directory in order to make that determination.  In my case all I know is that everything ought to be default with regards to extensions as I have never explicty added it in any way.

Which version of the Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions (firebase-functions) are you using? I've very recently experienced some problem when deploying with the latest version (5.1.0).

I think you're going to need the same "paperwork" in your question in order to get help here.  Can you add your firebase.json here?  Or can you list the steps for how to create a project from scratch that exhibits this behavior?  Stack Overflow typically requires a minimal complete reproducible example so others can know for sure what's going on.  Showing just the console message doesn't tell us much other than perhaps you installed an extension.
